# MonoDroid: Getting "TestFlightApp" like deployments

Tags: android, mono, monodevelop, xamarin.android, testflight

We took the plunge and bought Xamarin's Mono for Android. Works amazing!

We need to have our Android testers test the apps we make. For our iOS apps we deploy to test using TestFlightApp.com's Mobile Device Managment which is integrated into MonoDevelop.

What services or options do we have to similarly deploy our apps to Android testers all over the world?

Comment: One option is that with Android, you can easily upload and distribute apps to people directly as apks - but this isn't as forma a system as iOS TestFlight or WP7 Beta marketplace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TestFlight does Android releases now too!

Answer (score 3):

I found this to work: https://www.zubhium.com/

Comment: We also use Zubhium not only for beta distribution but for crash analysis & in app support desk. Covering complete life cycle of our app. Works great, made life easy.

Answer (score 1):

www.push-link.com is a great tool and it's free.

EDIT
You can now use the inbuilt Beta and Alpha tracks within the Google Play Console.